# Unzip all files in Directory and Subdirectory with specific file name windows 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new to powershell and batch scripting. 
I have a dir structure as

```
 Z:\abc\data1\dump data1 (2018 01)\dumpdata1_1705_as_tap.zip
 Z:\abc\data2\dump data2 (2018 01)\dumpdata2_1801_as_tap.zip
 Z:\abc\data3\dump data3 (2018 01)\dumpdata3_1802_as_tap.zip
 Z:\abc\data4\dump data4 (2018 01)\dumpdata4_1803_as_tap.zip
```

I want to unzip all the 1000+ files all having common name dumpdata_yymm_as_tap.zip as mentioned above. I want to unzip all of them to an different directory  eg.

```
f:\data1\dumpdata1_1705_as_tap.zip
f:\data1\dumpdata2_1801_as_tap.zip
```

while preserving it name as it is and I want them after an specific date say (2017 05) in the sub_directory folder.
How can we add regex in the batch file or powershell to only extract the data after (2017 05) to (2018 04).
I have 7-zip installed but cannot install python on it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not understanding your obfuscated examples. Please provide a more concrete and clear example of your folder structure and file names.

Comment: Your question is not about programming, but shell-scripting, please use https://superuser.com/ for such kind of questions

Comment: squashman does this helps;
I have to unzip all the files with the same name as zip name and unzip those to the f drive data1 folder

Answer (score 0):

We normally do not give out code unless the user has at least attempted to write some code of their own.  You know the whole, give a man a fish or teach a man to fish philosophy.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Find all zipped dumpdata files
FOR /R Z:\abc %%G IN (dumpdata*_*_as_tap.zip) DO (
    REM extract date from folder name date is surrounded by parentheses.
    FOR /F "TOKENS=2 delims=()" %%H IN ("%~pG") DO (
        SET "fdate=%%~H"
        REM remove space from date
        set "fdate=!fdate: =!
        REM check if date is between two dates
        IF !fdate! GTR 201705 IF !fdate! LEQ 201804 (
            REM 7zip command here.  %%G is your zip file name
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: thank you I did it with unzipping all the files first and then just copying them over to the data1 folder. I know I should have posted the code I was trying